# Responsive CSS @media queries

Tags: html, css, media, responsive

For making responsive my website I'm using media queries like this

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){code}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){code}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){code}
```

but when I try to test my website there is some issue I've facing. One kind of issue is @media 320px is alright but when I re-size  my webpage 320px to 480px or 640px by default 320px is coming and other two queries not working. Even I'm trying with min-width:320px but result is same. Now what should I do?
My another question is: What is the different between max-width and min width? and Which one should I use when?

Also tried this.
The code:

```css
    @media screen and (min-width: 320px){code}
    @media screen and (min-width: 480px){code}
    @media screen and (min-width: 640px){code}
```

Full responsive code,

The code:

```css
/*640px*/
@media screen and (min-width : 640px) {
    .colum {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .navbar-header h1 {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .welcome_text h4 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .welcome_text h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .promo_title h1, .work_title h1 {
        max-width: 640px;
    }
    .promo_title p, .work_title p{font-size: 18px;
    color: #7e8287;
    width: 620px;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .promo_list{
        margin-bottom: 390px;
    }
    
    .fix1{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .clear1 {
        clear: both;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .extramarg {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .rightborder {
    position: absolute;   
    height: 175px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d9dbdb;
    right: 313px;
    }
    .single_list {
        border-right: none;
        width: 315px;
    }
    .rightimg {
        background: none;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        opacity:0;
    }
    .service_list {
        padding: 60px 25px 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .leftarea {
        width: 640px;
        padding: 0 25px;
    }
    .service_list h1:before {
        left: 36%;
    }
    .service_item .ss_list {
        width: 295px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .work_title p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .work_slider {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .slider_detail h3 {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
    .promo_title h1, .work_title h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .msg_area .colum {
        width: 640px;
    }
    .msg_area textarea {
        width: 570px;
    }
    .contact input[type="text"], .contact input[type="email"] {
        width: 540px;
    }
    .submit a {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .promo_title, .work_title {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
}

/*480 */
@media screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    .colum {
        max-width: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .navbar-header h1 {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .welcome_text h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    }
    .welcome_text h4 {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .promo_title h1, .work_title h1 {
        max-width: 320px;
    }
    .promo_title p, .work_title p{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7e8287;
    width: 340px;
    padding:0;
    }
    .single_list {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d9dbdb;
        border-right: 0;
        padding: 20px 0;
        width: 320px;
    }
    .promo_list div:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    .promo_area {
        margin-bottom: -230px;
    }
    .floatleft {
        float: none;
    }
    .leftarea {
        width: 320px;
    }
    .leftarea h1 {
       text-align: center
    }
    .service_list p {
            padding: 35px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .service_list h1:before {
        left:75px;
    }
    .service_list h1 {
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    .service_list {
        padding: 60px 0;
    }
    .service_item .ss_list {
        width: 320px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        }
    .work_slider {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .slider_detail h3 {
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
    .promo_title h1, .work_title h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .rightimg {
      background:none;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      width:0;
      height: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .contact input[type="text"], .contact input[type="email"], .contact textarea{
        width:320px;
    }
    .submit a {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .promo_title, .work_title {
        padding: 40px 0;
    }
}


/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    .colum {
        max-width: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .navbar-header h1 {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .welcome_text h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    }
    .welcome_text h4 {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .promo_title h1, .work_title h1 {
        max-width: 320px;
    }
    .promo_title p, .work_title p{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7e8287;
    width: 300px;
    padding:0;
    }
    .single_list {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d9dbdb;
        border-right: 0;
        padding: 20px 0;
        width: 320px;
    }
    .promo_list div:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    .promo_area {
        margin-bottom: -230px;
    }
    .floatleft {
        float: none;
    }
    .leftarea {
        width: 320px;
    }
    .leftarea h1 {
       text-align: center
    }
    .service_list p {
            padding: 35px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .service_list h1:before {
        left:75px;
    }
    .service_list h1 {
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    .service_list {
        padding: 60px 0;
    }
    .service_item .ss_list {
        width: 320px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        }
        .work_slider {
        width: 100%;
        }
    .slider_detail h3 {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
    .promo_title h1, .work_title h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .rightimg {
      background:none;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      width:0;
      height: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .contact input[type="text"], .contact input[type="email"], .contact textarea{
        width:320px;
    }
    .submit a {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .promo_title, .work_title {
        padding: 40px 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: put the @media queries in reverse order as for the queries are true for all 3 cases

Comment: do you mean 320px then 480px then 640px?

Comment: yes.. that will make the queries run as intended..

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's wrong code..
@media screen and (min-width: 320px){
this code will run at screen 320px and above 
if you put the code here of course this code will run at 480px and 680px
}

top prevent that code from the 480px and 680px
Make it like this 
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px){
the code here
}

Answer (score 0):

Try blow code:

`@media screen and (max-width: 320px){code}`
`@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {code}`
`@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 640px) {code}`
I hope your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightcoral;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
<p>The media query will only apply if the media type is screen and the viewport is 480px wide or wider.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

(edit note: corrected a few typos and errors)

You have to consider that CSS is "cascading" (= falling down), which means: If you have two different rules for the same element, the latter (= lower) will override the earlier one. So in your first code example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){code}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){code}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){code}
```

anything that is written inside the third media query (max-width: 640) will override what is written in the first one, since everything that's below 320px wide, is *also* below 640px wide.

So you have two choices:

1.) Turn around the order:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){code}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){code}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){code}
```

That way, if the screen is 300px wide, it will first follow the rules from the first two queries, but then also the ones in the third query, which will override the others. That's called a desktop-first approach, since it first lists the rules for bigger (desktop) screens (above the media queries), which are then overridden by the rules for smaller devices in three steps (first maximum 640, then 480, then 320px). So a 450px wide phablet will read the rules in the first and second query (with the second overriding the first) and then stop and ignore the rules in the third media query, since it's *not* below 320px wide.

As an alternative:

2.) Use the media queries in ascending order, but with min-width:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px){code}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px){code}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px){code}
```

That's a mobile-first approach: It first lists the rules for mobile (i.e. everything that's *at least* 320px wide) and then goes further up. So a 360px device will stop reading the rules after the second media query, a desktop computer will read all three, and again, the rules in the third rule will overrule the ones in the first query.